# Is NSTextAttachment image animation possible?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview

Using iOS7 I'm able to display images in a UITextView with no problem using NSTextAttachments. However, is it possible to show animated images in a UITextView using NSTextAttachments? If so, how?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No. It doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate images in NSTextAttachment you need to attach a `CADisplayLink` to the `UITextView` and change the images manually. After that you should call `layoutManager.invalidateDisplay(forCharacterRange: ATTACHMENT_RANGE)` to refresh the textView layout